# Calling a Recordset based on a textbox value

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I need to call out a group of record stored in a MS Access database. So far I've managed to display all the records, but I need to display specific ones based on a folio number, which is stored in a userform textbox.

I've tried to change the `WHERE Folio = me.tbFolio.Value` multiple times, but I just can't get it right, it keeps on showing all the recordsets on the database.

```vb
Private Sub Srch_Click()
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset, r As Long, sSQL As String, Fl As Long
    Let Fl = tbFolio.Value - 1
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=S:\Common\Quality\RASTREABILIDAD\MAIN PROJECT\PROYECTO KOREANO MX.accdb;"
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open "Trazabilidad", cn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdTable
    sSQL = "SELECT [Folio], [N° de Orden, Fecha], [N° de Parte, Materiales], [N° de Parte Material], [N° de Lote/Fecha de Proucción], [Quién Capturo]" & _
        "FROM Trazabilidad" & _
        "WHERE Folio = me.tbfolio.value;"
    MsgBox rs.GetString, vbOKOnly, "Trazabilidad"
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Try changing "WHERE Folio = me.tbfolio.value;" to "WHERE Folio = '" & me.tbfolio.value & "';"

Answer (score 0):

You should try to concatenate (using &) the value from text box , to put this 
value inside your query

```vb
  Private Sub Srch_Click()
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset, r As Long, sSQL As String, Fl As Long
    Let Fl = tbFolio.Value - 1
        Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
        cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
            "Data Source=S:\Common\Quality\RASTREABILIDAD\MAIN PROJECT\PROYECTO KOREANO MX.accdb;"
        Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
        rs.Open "Trazabilidad", cn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdTable
        sSQL = "SELECT [Folio], [N° de Orden, Fecha], [N° de Parte, Materiales], [N° de Parte Material], [N° de Lote/Fecha de Proucción], [Quién Capturo]" & _
            "FROM Trazabilidad" & _
            "WHERE Folio = " &  me.tbfolio.value
        MsgBox rs.GetString, vbOKOnly, "Trazabilidad"
        cn.Close
        Set cn = Nothing
    End Sub
```

if it is a string
change

```
"WHERE Folio = " &  me.tbfolio.value
```

for

```
"WHERE Folio = '" &  me.tbfolio.value & "'"
```